# JQuery click function not firing off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

The problem I am running into is that I have this responsive navigation built. I only want it to dropdown when the hamburger icon is clicked, but it will not work if I try targeting it. It only works if I target the entire navbar it is nested in.

Here is a link to a local jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cheyneosy_/ytZr5/)

### HTML Code

```
<div class="toggleMenu">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" id="toggle-btn"></button>
</div>

<nav class="level-nav hidden-md">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pulses</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kudos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Blogs</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Resources <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <div class="level-inner">
        <span class="split"></span>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

### JQuery Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var mobileMenu = $(".level-nav li a");
  $(mobileMenu).each(function() {
    if ($(this).next().length > 0) {
        $(this).addClass("parent");
    };
  })

  /* Defined variables for main and sub multi-level navigations */
  var subNav = $("#toggle-btn");

  /* Function that activates the sub-navigation bar to toggle the sibiling which is the  .level-nav */
  $(subNav).click(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings(".level-nav").toggle(175, "easeInQuad");
  });
});
```

Comment: Your title is not accurate. The click handler is working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/ytZr5/1/

Comment: Your toggle button has no siblings

Comment: @durrrutti http://cdn.css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/threelines.png this is what I am talking about. I know it is not showing up on my fiddle but that is only because of not having all of bootstrap being able to work in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is not a sibling of the navigation, it's wrapped in a DIV that is a sibling of the navigation

```
$(this).closest('.toggleMenu').siblings(".level-nav").toggle(175, "easeInQuad");
```

And to use `toggle()` like that, you'll have to include jQuery UI as well

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ytZr5/3/)

Comment: I am surprised you did not undo the `$(subNav)` even though it works like that

Comment: @Huangism - yeah, wrapping it twice defeats the entire purpose of caching it, but I didn't want to rewrite everything, and it's not really an error, just inefficient.

Comment: @Huangism Sorry about that... I am still a rookie with JQuery and still have much to learn. So I really do appreciate all the input you and adeneo are giving me.

Comment: @adeneo sir is there a way to add another click in the sample for example i want to add another action on `about me` in the drop down menu for example i want an alert saying `about me clicked` how is it possible?